# PowerShell Pscx Expand-Archive method failure detection

Tags: powershell, error-handling, pscx

PowerShell snippet:

```
Import-Module Pscx
Expand-Archive ConsoleApplication1.zip ./
Write-Host $?
Write-Host $LastExitCode
```

Neither `$?` nor `$LastExitCode` report about error. But there is error, because file ConsoleApplication1.exe is locked (i started this app). I can see failure by following output:

```
WARNING: ArchiveCallBack->GetStream error: System.IO.IOException:
The process cannot access the file 'D:\tmp\ConsoleApplication1.exe'
 because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
...
```

**Question**: how can I detect in powershell that Expand-Archive failed

Thanks

Comment: Hi Roman - please log a bug on pscx.codeplex.com and I'll fix this for the next release - Oisin.

Comment: Hi Oisin. Done: http://pscx.codeplex.com/workitem/30139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've found solution that works:

```
$w = $null
Expand-Archive ConsoleApplication1.zip ./ -WarningVariable w
```

If error occurs (or call them warnings) they are collected in $w variable. If `$w.Count -gt 0` it means some error/warning have occured.

Comment: Nice workaround - please submit an issue on pscx.codeplex.com anyway... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$LastExitCode` is purely for native EXE exit codes. It doesn't apply to cmdlets.  `$?` should work if the cmdlet detects that it has errored and writes out an error object. It appears this cmdlet isn't internally detecting the error. If you run `$error.Clear()`, then the `Expand-Archive` command, does `$error[0]` contain an error?

Also, is it possible that the cmdlet is still expanding the exe when you try to execute it?  I assume you're waiting for the cmdlet to finish before attempting to execute the console app.  I guess it's also possible there's a bug where the file is being closed/disposed.  What if you try a `[gc]::collect()` after the `Expand-Archive`.  Do you still get the error?

Comment: `$errors.Count` remains the same. With console app - it is only an example how to make `Expand-Archive` cmd-let fail. The main idea was to somehow lock the file

Comment: In that case, Expand-Archive doesn't think it failed so using $? is a no go.

Comment: My bad - I really should be writing a non-termating error instead of a warning record.