# Identifying Failed File on Expand-Archive

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am using PowerShell 5. I am using Expand-Archive to unzip files containing several thousand files. All works well most of the time but occasionally we get a bad filename in a zip. In my test-case the pdf file within the zip file has a colon ':' in the name, which causes the failure.

This is a scheduled task that should run silently, only reporting back if there is an error. On error, it should complete, but send an error warning. Optimally I would like to know both the archive name, and on which file within the archive it failed so I can add it to the report. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried the -WarningVariable switch described here: [PowerShell Pscx Expand-Archive method failure detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953582/powershell-pscx-expand-archive-method-failure-detection) but had no content in the variable.

My current code sends a report, but the report contains only the name of the archive. I see no way to obtain the name of the file within the archive that causes the failure:

```
$file_list | ForEach-Object {

    try{
        Expand-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath $input_temp -force
    }
    catch {
        Send-MailMessage -from "email@address" -to "email@address" -subject $subject  -body "File ($need_to_know_on_which_file_the_extract_failed) failed to extract from $($_.FullName)" -SmtpServer smtp.server
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($zipFile)
$files = $zip.items().count
if ($files -gt 0) {
    foreach($item in $zip.items()){
        if ($item.name -like "*.pdf") {
            Write-Verbose "File: $($item.name)"
            try {               
                $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item,0x14)
            }
            catch {
                Send-MailMessage -from "email@address" -to "email@address" -subject $subject  -body "File ($need_to_know_on_which_file_the_extract_failed) failed to extract from $($_.FullName)" -SmtpServer smtp.server
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

This lets me get the name of the problem file within the archive if I run it manually, since it outputs just before trying the copyhere, but the try/catch doesn't work because on error it pops up an application screen which stops the script and no report is sent.

Comment: Use `-ErrorAction Stop` on your `Expand-Archive` call.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear that this is a scheduled task that should run silently and on error it should complete and report out the name of the archive and the file within the archive on which it failed.

Comment: You should Google what terminating errors are..